# available smallest width quantifiers

Tags: android, android-layout, screen

I am trying to create an application which works fine on mobile devices with small screen and tablet devices having large screen. That is devices with  screen size 4 to 10 inch.

Read that we can resolve this issue by using smallest width qualifier .

> The Smallest-width qualifier allows you to target screens that have a
>   certain minimum width given in dp

May i know the available smallest width qualifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typical numbers for screen width dp are:

- 320: a phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
- 480: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
- 600: a 7” tablet (600x1024).
- 720: a 10” tablet (720x1280, 800x1280, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Smallest smartphone screens typically have a smallest width of 320 dp, but you can put the resources for the minimum screen size you are willing to support in the `drawable`, `drawable-sw0dp` or `drawable-sw320dp` folders, or, more in general, any `drawable-sw<N>dp` folder with N <= 320. If you want to choose a minimum screen size to support for your app, you should use the corresponding manifest attribute:

```
<supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="320"/>
```

and not with resource folder names, to avoid runtime crashes.